# Preencher um vetor utilizando o useDelimiter em Java

Tags: java, array

Olá, estou querendo preencher um vetor utilizando o `useDelimiter` do Java. Por enquanto só sei preencher um vetor desta maneira utilizando o for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Digite um número: ");
            vet[i] = s.nextInt();
            soma += vet[i];
        }
```

neste exercício preciso calcular a média dos itens dentro do vetor.

A entrada do usuário seria esta:

```
3;9;4;5;8;0;1;8;5;1;3;2;6;4;7;
```

Pesquisando encontrei o `useDelimiter` como alternativa, mas ainda não entendo como ele poderia funcionar nesse cenário. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico muito agradecido!

Answer (score 0):

Se quer ler a string de uma vez e separar os valores não precisa usar o `useDelimiter`, pode usar o `split` para separar a string em um array.

No exemplo abaixo faço isso, gerando um array de string (string para string) e a seguir faço um `for` para ler os valores e somar e/ou criar um array de int:

```
// aqui pode usar o Scanner para ler a string, nesse exemplo, deixei fixo
String numsString = "3;9;4;5;8;0;1;8;5;1;3;2;6;4;7";
// converte para um array de string, usando o separador ";"
String[] numsStringArray = numsString.split(";");

int[] numsIntArray = new int[numsStringArray.length];
int soma = 0;
// converte para um array de int
// poderia apenas somar, deixei o exemplo mais generico a quem possa interessar
for (int i = 0; i < numsIntArray.length; i++)
{
  numsIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsStringArray[i]);
  soma += numsIntArray[i];
}

System.out.println(soma);
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/AERwSIJ